# Is there a way to calculate an average using JS code?

Tags: javascript

I’m trying to calculate an average using Javascript, and have following code to show you. I am building an application where I need to calculate an average score.

I have been trying to build a calculator using JavaScript in which you click on two radio buttons and trying to get an average after you click a button. You can find the HTML code for the radio buttons below:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div style = "text-align:center">
            APS Calculator 
            <form action=""  id="calculator" onsubmit="fn1 ()>
            Maths
            <p>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS Maths" value="9">9<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS Maths" value="8">8<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS Maths" value="7">7<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS Maths" value="6">6<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS Maths" value="5">5<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS Maths" value="4">4<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS Maths" value="3">3<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS Maths" value="2">2<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS Maths" value="1">1<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS Maths" value="0">0<br>
            </p>
            English
            <p>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS English" value="9">9<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS English" value="8">8<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS English" value="7">7<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS English" value="6">6<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS English" value="5">5<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS English" value="4">4<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS English" value="3">3<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS English" value="2">2<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS English" value="1">1<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS English" value="0">0<br>

            <br>
                <button onclick="fn1 ()" id = "btn1"> Click Me</button>



            </p>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Whenever I click the button after choosing two radio buttons, the output comes out as either "Your APS is : NaN" or there is no output at all. Can I find a way to output an average based on the buttons that i have clicked?

Here is the JavaScript code:

```js
var EnglishStudent = parseInt(document.getElementsByName('APS English'));
var MathsStudent = parseInt(document.getElementsByName('APS Maths'));
var avg = (EnglishStudent + MathsStudent) / 2;

function fn1(EnglishStudent, MathsStudent)

{
  var EnglishStudent = parseInt(document.getElementsByName('APS English'));
  var MathsStudent = parseInt(document.getElementsByName('APS Maths'));
  var avg = (EnglishStudent + MathsStudent) / 2;
  return avg;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div style = "text-align:center">
            APS Calculator 
            <form action=""  id="calculator" onsubmit="fn1 ()>
            Maths
            <p>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS Maths" value="9">9<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS Maths" value="8">8<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS Maths" value="7">7<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS Maths" value="6">6<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS Maths" value="5">5<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS Maths" value="4">4<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS Maths" value="3">3<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS Maths" value="2">2<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS Maths" value="1">1<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS Maths" value="0">0<br>
            </p>
            English
            <p>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS English" value="9">9<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS English" value="8">8<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS English" value="7">7<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS English" value="6">6<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS English" value="5">5<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS English" value="4">4<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS English" value="3">3<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS English" value="2">2<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS English" value="1">1<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "APS English" value="0">0<br>

            <br>
                <button onclick="fn1 ()" id = "btn1"> Click Me</button>



            </p>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welome to Stackoverflow. There are many syntax mistakes in your code that should be fixed, but for now I'm very curious about this statement: _the output comes out_ - where, exactly does the output come out? I'm curious because the code you provided doesn't produce any output in any form.

Answer (score 0):

So there is a lot of issues here:

- Firstoff - doing this with radio buttons is just not really cool (lets say it this way)
- Second: You can't have and unclosed `onsubmit="fn1 ()` attribute. it needs to be `onsubmit="fn1 ()"` with a closing `"`.
- Next thing is, you can't just access the selected radio button with `document.getElementsByName('APS English')`, because this will give you all the elements with `name="APS English"` - also this is why I would suggest getting rid of the radio buttons. Radio buttons don`t have any active state or any kind of that, so that you could access them in js, unless you set an anttribute on each and every one of them, whenever they change. I would much rather do something like this:

```js
function fn1(EnglishStudent, MathsStudent){
var EnglishStudent = parseInt(document.getElementById("math").value);
var MathsStudent = parseInt(document.getElementById("english").value);
var avg = (EnglishStudent + MathsStudent) / 2;
  alert(avg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div style = "text-align:center">
            APS Calculator 
            <form action=""  id="calculator" onsubmit="fn1()">
            Maths
            <p>
            <input id="math" type = "text" name = "APS Maths"><br>
            </p>
            English
            <p>
            <input id="english" type = "text" name = "APS English"><br>
            <br>
                <button id = "btn1"> Click Me</button>



            </p>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

P.S.: And don't call your function `fn1()` twice.

Right now you are calling it once, on the form submit, and once when the button is clicked, wich will fire it twice, and we don`t want that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this form is based on the following links, which is why radio buttons are being used: https://www.sgmc.ac.uk/courses/entryReqs.asp.   You select an option under the dropdown menu "Please select how many GCSEs you are studying" and then select radio buttons.

Comment: Please add that you HAVE to use Radio buttons. As I said, you will then have to implement a function that checks if any of your radio button changes, and set a specific value for it that you can access in you function. On your referenced site, if you look into the html code, this is done with `onchange="updateAPSBarAndOfferings()"` on all the radio button element.  All the other problems should be solved firstly, still...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other issues mentioned, CSS selectors can be used to find the selected radios :

```js
var a = document.querySelector("input[name='APS Maths']:checked");
var b = document.querySelector("input[name='APS English']:checked");

if (a && b)
  document.write( (+a.value + +b.value) / 2 )
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="APS Maths" value="8">8
<input type="radio" name="APS Maths" value="7" checked>7
<input type="radio" name="APS Maths" value="6">6
<br>
<input type="radio" name="APS English" value="4">4
<input type="radio" name="APS English" value="3" checked>3
<input type="radio" name="APS English" value="2">2
<br>
Average:
```

Answer (score 0):

In previous replies, you have been pointed out some shortcomings in your code, so i won't do the same. I maybe found solution for you problem. Below is my code how would i do that.

```js
function fn1() {
        var m = document.getElementsByName("APS Maths");
        var e = document.getElementsByName("APS English");
        var avg = 0;

        avg += getAvg(m);
        avg += getAvg(e);

        alert(avg / 2);
    }

    function getAvg(arg) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arg.length; i++) {
            if (arg[i].checked) {
                return parseInt(arg[i].value, 10);
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div style="text-align:center">
            APS Calculator
            <form action="">
                Maths
                <p>
                    <input type="radio" name="APS Maths" value="9" />9<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="APS Maths" value="8" />8<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="APS Maths" value="7" />7<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="APS Maths" value="6" />6<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="APS Maths" value="5" />5<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="APS Maths" value="4" />4<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="APS Maths" value="3" />3<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="APS Maths" value="2" />2<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="APS Maths" value="1" />1<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="APS Maths" value="0" />0<br>
                </p>
                English
                <p>
                    <input type="radio" name="APS English" value="9" />9<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="APS English" value="8" />8<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="APS English" value="7" />7<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="APS English" value="6" />6<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="APS English" value="5" />5<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="APS English" value="4" />4<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="APS English" value="3" />3<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="APS English" value="2" />2<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="APS English" value="1" />1<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="APS English" value="0" />0<br>

                    <br>
                    <button onclick="fn1()" id="btn1"> Click Me</button>
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this.